# Enumerating pairs of disconnected cliques in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

**Note:** This problem is exactly same as problem on this [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85769/enumerating-pairs-of-disconnected-cliques-in-a-graph?noredirect=1#comment183870_85769).

Given an unweighted graph $G = (V,E)$. I am interested in enumerating all pairs of <strike>disjoint</strike> disconnected cliques. A clique could be of any size $\geq 1$.

Are there any standard approaches to solve this problem? If so, could someone please highlight the sources or suggest some approaches?

EDIT: By disjoint cliques, I originally meant cliques that are disconnected, i.e. there should exists no edge across the two cliques. Perhaps I used the wrong terminology earlier.

Comment: It is best to ask a new question (which links back to the original) when you have an edit to your original question of this magnitude

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that finding the largest clique in a graph is NP Hard. (See, for example, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).) So if the graph is not complete, it is NP-hard to just find the pair of cliques containing a maximal clique and another another clique (perhaps, say, of size $1$).

There are also in general going to be very large numbers of such pairs, even for small graphs. For the complete graph on $n$ vertices, any choice of $k<n$ vertices is a clique. From there you are allowed to pick any clique out of the remaining $n-k$ vertices. There are $2^{n-1} - 1$ partitions of $K_n$ into two disjoint cliques and there are even more pairs of disjoint cliques than that. Granted, the complete graph is a worst case, but for any graph you meet in practice, your problem appears to me to be intractable.

Comment: By disjoint cliques, I meant "edge disjoint" cliques, i.e. there should not exist any edge across the cliques. Therefore, in a complete graph, there exists no pair of disjoint cliques. Sorry for the confusion though.

Comment: Now I realize that even "edge disjoint" is a wrong term. Actually I am looking for cliques that are disconnected.

Comment: Consider a graph with two connected components, each isomorphic to $K_{n/2}$. Then every clique in the first component (of which there are $2^{n/2}-1$ is disconnected from every clique in the second component (of which there are $2^{n/2}-1$.) This is still an exponential problem in the worst case

Comment: And, in general, you still might have to find the largest clique in the graph (if that maximal clique is part of a pair of disconnected cliques), which is still NP Hard

Comment: Certainly! The problem is NP Hard. Nevertheless, I am looking for heuristic approaches, especially if there are any well-known ones

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal [Computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com) may have people who know more of this.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion. I have posted there now as well.

Comment: It would probably be considered polite there to link to this question to indicate the duplication

Comment: Not that it helps any, but it's the same problem as finding the number of (nonempty) complete bipartite graphs in the complement of $G.$